# Initialization of backend tensorflow failed Error: Could not locate the bindings file

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js

I'm receiving this error when trying to use tensorflow on an ubuntu box.  It's a fresh npm install in a new folder.  I've tried the suggestions from other posts but still can't get it.  Is there something I'm missing?

> Initialization of backend tensorflow failed
>   Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
>    → /var/nodejs/tensor/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/build/tfjs_binding.node,
>   ... etc

node: v10.12.0

npm: 6.7.0

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "tensor",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node algo.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "*"
  }
}
```

### algo.js

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the following steps might help to fix your problem:

- **Do a clean installation of your dependencies**

  - Delete the the `node_modules` folder
  - Rerun `npm install`
- **(Re)install node-gyp:**

  - `sudo npm install -g node-gyp`
- **Install your dependencies via `sudo`**

  - `sudo npm install`
  - If this step works, it is very likely that you are having a permission issue in your directory structure. You might want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16151018/5627599) on how to resolve the issue.